# Search engine - App Engine

Tags: html, google-app-engine, jsp, seo

I have a newly created web application hosted in AppEngine (only HTML)
The question is, how can I make this page appear on Google Search Engine? Is this like the regular method (robot.txt, etc.) ?

Thanks!

Comment: Note that it's `robots.txt` (*not* `robot.txt`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two easy steps to notify Google about your new website

1. Create a [sitemap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sitemaps) for your static pages. You can use some on-line sitemap creator e.g. http://www.xml-sitemaps.com/
2. Create new account for your website in [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en) and add your newly created sitemap over there (Optimization > Sitemap).

[image: Google Webmaster Tools Sitemap]

You can also use [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en) to check status of your website indexing (Health > Indexing Status).

[image: Google Webmaster Tools Indexing Status]

I hope that will help.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, one thing you could do is to add your website to Google Webmaster Tools (https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home)

If you have news on your website, you can also submit your content on
http://support.google.com/news/publisher/bin/topic.py?hl=en&topic=2484652

You can also submit your website to Google Analytics: http://www.google.com/analytics/

To check after a few days/weeks whether your site is crawled by google after the submission, type
`site:yourwebsitename.com` into the google search bar.

If you are further interested to add your site to Bing Search, try this link: http://www.bing.com/toolbox/submit-site-url